# MS Access: Substitutes for Upsizing Wizard (SSMA?)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016, sql-server-migration-assi, upsizing

Our team has been using Microsoft Access 2010 as a frontend for an SQL Server 2014, and are dependent on the Upsizing Wizard in Access to migrate tables from Access to SQL.

For example, if there is an SQL database named `papers`, our team has an Access file named `papers_temp.accdb`. When we want to make changes to a given table (or create a new table) in the papers database, we do this locally in `papers_temp.accdb` before using the upsizing wizard to migrate the given table from Access to the SQL database, overwriting the table in SQL if it already exists.

From Office 2013 and Access 2013, the Upsizing Wizard is gone, and we are in need of an alternative. Is there a similar tool available for Access 2016, or do we have to adapt to something else entirely? So far open to suggestions.

---

**SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access**

I've been exploring this program for the last couple of days, after finding many recommendations for it on the web. It appears to be able to do the upsizing and migration that we need.

However, more often that not, when attempting to select (and load) a table, the program is stuck in a loading process that never seems to end (tried waiting for one hour), meaning I'm forced to close SSMA without saving my project. In general, the program does not seem very stable, and we'd prefer to find a solution that was more familiar to work with.

Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: That is (was) a strange way of doing things, always overwriting the complete table. Don't you have existing data that must be preserved?

Comment: @Andre The SQL side is never changed from what has been migrated from the .accdb, so the overwrite includes what is already on the server. Yes, it is somewhat unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, the upsizing wizard has been deprecated and the replacement is (SSMA).

The latest version as of today is:

**Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 8.5 for Access**

https://aka.ms/ssmaforaccess

In my testing I have learned that it is not compatible with the 2019 O365 version of DAO and you cannot install the correct version of DAO along side O365. This means that this solution is dead in the water. Microsoft has updated us in to a corner where we can't use any of their previous solutions on the latest version of Access. At this point I think we are waiting for MS to update the tools to support the latest version of O365 Access.

If you are stuck in this boat with us the only other option is 3rd party software.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up making a workaround VBA script instead of trying to find a substitute to the old functionality. The script basically upsizes tables by querying the remote SQL, and allows our users to do more or less what they used to except they need to interface with a custom menu in Access.